# IntelliJ debug maven package included in EAR

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

After deploying an EAR to a local Weblogic instance, I'm remote debugging the application without problems.

However, I cannot seem to get debug connection to a maven package that I've added as a maven dependency to the project (jar).

Debug config:

[image]

Showing working debug connection in source code:

[image]

Not working debug on included Maven package:

[image]

How to solve this?

Note: I checked the deployed ear, the jar is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ actually works as it should.
The micrometere-registry-influx jar was properly included in the ear, but not properly plugged into the the application due to a wrong JavaEE annotation which failed the EJB to be registered.
Hence the micrometer core package didn't use the influx plugin as expected.